# PDF book opens in Mendeley when openned from Calibre

Tags: 16.04, pdf, i3-wm, calibre, mendeley

I have Ubuntu Gnome installed and I am using i3wm. Everytime I double click a book in Calibre to open it it opens in [Mendeley desktop](https://www.mendeley.com/download-mendeley-desktop/ubuntu/instructions/).

This doesn't happen under Gnome.

Could you explain why this happens and how I can fix it?

Comment: I have the same problem; `texdoc` also opens PDFs with Mendeley, but Thunar behaves normally and opens evince.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be that `xdg-open` is misconfigured:

```
$ xdg-mime query default application/pdf
mendeleydesktop.desktop
```

Sure enough, if I run `xdg-open some.pdf` it opens with Mendeley. It seems that some applications use `xdg-open` while others don't.

According to [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Default_applications#Set_the_default_browser), the culprit should be in here:

```
$ cat /usr/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache | grep pdf
application/pdf=evince-previewer.desktop;gimp.desktop;evince.desktop;mendeleydesktop.desktop;
application/x-bzpdf=evince-previewer.desktop;evince.desktop;
application/x-ext-pdf=evince-previewer.desktop;evince.desktop;
application/x-gzpdf=evince-previewer.desktop;evince.desktop;
application/x-xzpdf=evince-previewer.desktop;evince.desktop;
image/pdf=display-im6.q16.desktop;display-im6.desktop;
```

Looks good to me, except GIMP being there; oh well.

```
$ cat .config/mimeapps.list | grep pdf
application/pdf=evince.desktop;inkscape.desktop;
```

Looks fine as well. So the problem could be in an i3-specific config file. But:

```
$ echo $XDG_CONFIG_DIRS
/etc/xdg/xdg-i3:/etc/xdg
```

The former folder does not exist, and the second does not contain any `.list` file.

So I have no idea where this comes from. But running

```
xdg-mime default evince.desktop application/pdf
```

does certainly fix it.

Comment: [Follow-up question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/398141/17409).

Comment: That question led to a [script](https://github.com/reitzig/scripts/blob/master/xdg-mime-which.sh) that finds where the default application is set. Not why or by whom, though.